# jQuery keyboard events on DOM elements

Tags: jquery, keyboard, interactive

I'm building a project where I will have two divs which have their CSS switched up on different individual keypresses.

I am using this jQuery library: https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/

You can see a simple demo here: http://lazarogamio.com/projects/key_test/

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="test_box" id="red"></div>

<div class="test_box" id="green"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
.test_box {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 2px solid #000;
margin: 20px;
float: left;
}

.red {
background-color: red;
}

.green {
background-color: green;
}
```

And my jQuery:

```
function keymap(){

$(document).bind('keydown', 'r', function (evt){
    $('#red').toggleClass('red');
    });

$(document).bind('keydown', 'g', function (evt){
    $('#green').toggleClass('green');
    });
};

$(document).ready(keymap);
```

At the moment, the keydown event is working, but for every key, and for both divs. I originally had each div controlled by a separate function, but my results were the same. I also tried to map other keys to do nothing, to no avail. My hunch is that I am not targeting the keys properly, or perhaps not binding the function to the correct object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including `hotkeys` *before* you include jQuery.  It needs to be the other way around.  Currently, you're just binding to `keydown` like normal and the `hotkeys` include has no effect.

If you include jQuery first, it should work as you expect:

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/GGvrd/

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was this simple. Thanks a bunch!