# customizing firefox console.log (for my own prototype)

Tags: javascript, linux, firefox

I'm coding a (free software) application (the MELT monitor, on GNU/Linux/Debian/x86-64) which embeds its specific web server.

<sup>See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33540051/841108) for gory details. If interested, look into commit [880419d370d749](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/commit/880419d370d7494f0587dffdc8e71f144b7ec81f) on github then build it, run `./monimelt -Dweb,run -W localhost.localdomain:8086/` and open http://localhost.localdomain:8086/canvedit.html in your Firefox. FWIW I'm now trying to use canvases. Relevant code might go in my [webroot/canvasedit.js](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/blob/master/webroot/canvedit.js), but I don't know what to code there yet...</sup>

Firefox is version 38 or 42. I don't understand all the details of [ConsoleAPI.js](https://github.com/mozilla-services/services-central-legacy/blob/master/dom/base/ConsoleAPI.js) which probably is very relevant to my question.

Let suppose I have a prototype

```
var fooproto = {
  // perhaps adding a toString function is enough here?
  // I want to show num & sons
};
```

then I make some objects using it:

```
var foo1 = Object();
foo1.num = 11;
foo1.__proto__ = fooproto;

var foo2 = Object();
foo2.num = 37;
foo2.sons = [foo1];
foo2.__proto__ = fooproto;
```

I would like

```
console.log("foo2=", foo2);
```

to show something like `foo2=`*Foo#37[Foo#11]* on the console (if possible with the italics)

Is there a way to change `fooproto` to make that work? I guess that some mechanism exist, since `console.log` is displaying nicely DOM objects.

<sup>It is probably a FAQ asked many times, but I was not able after several minutes of searching to find the appropriate search keywords. I don't know what terminology to use</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I’m not developing for Firefox and apologies if you’ve already seen this, but I’ve stumbled across this:

- [Custom output in the Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Custom_output) on MDN, and specifically [console API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console)

Seems like something that might answer your needs.

Comment: On second thought console API may not answer your need fully since it has only limited formatting capabilities. However, custom output seems to be pretty flexible if you’re willing to dive in—it’s among the docs intended for plugin developers, I think