# contenteditable with nested span. Who has the focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, linux, html, firefox

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33540051/841108) (to which I added a bounty) is related and gives the context and motivations (my GPLv3 [MELT monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015) on github; I added at last some README to it).

I am only interested in *recent* HTML5 compliant browsers (on GNU/Linux), e.g. Firefox 38 at least (and preferably 42) or Chrome 46 (on Debian/Sid desktop, x86-64)

So, suppose I have in my HTML5 page

```
<div id='myeditdiv' contenteditable='true'>
  <span class='foo_cl'>FOO<span class='bar_cl'>bar</span></span>
</div>
```

<sup>(actually the HTML is generated, and so is the DOM; I'm currently generating on the server side some javascript which constructs the DOM; of course I can change the generators!)</sup>

And I am clicking so that the focus come between the two `OO`. How can I get the DOM element of `foo_cl`, preferably with Jquery.

Same question when focusing between `ar`. I want the `bar_cl` span.

Of course, `$(':focus')` don't work. It gives the `div`

FWIW, it is commit [9109ae5b3d168f1](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/commit/9109ae5b3d168f16bd78d170079c6594e4d3f32e) of the MELT monitor.

PS. See my (november 26<sup>th</sup> 2015) addenda to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33540051/841108). Probably `contenteditable` is not useful to me, but `tabindex` surely is useful!

Comment: If you set `tabindex` attribute, you can make these elements focusable: http://jsfiddle.net/rex7dwc2/

Comment: @A.Wolff, why don't you post it as an answer? I looks like a valid answer to me.

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo I'm not sure it is really what OP is looking for, meaning changing HTML markup

Comment: @A.Wolff: That would make a good answer. Do you have any references, or is that behavior specific to one browser only?

Comment: This is spec regarding `tabindex` attribute and ya it is consistent across browser: http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0101/0101-TABINDEX.html  FYI, setting negative tabindex value makes element focusable but not tabbable. Now you need to test regarding `event.relatedTarget` because AFAIK this is normalized by jQuery **just**  for mouse events, not for `focus` ones e.g. And i'll post it as answer when i'll get more time in hands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make any element focusable, not only interactive content ones, you have to set [tabindex attribute](http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0101/0101-TABINDEX.html).

In your sample, it would be:

```
<div id='myeditdiv' contenteditable='true'>
  <span class='foo_cl' tabindex="-1">FOO<span class='bar_cl' tabindex="-1">bar</span</span>
</div>
```

***Note:*** negative `tabindex` makes element focusable **but** not tabbable because using tabbing method would start at `0` using absolute value ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-forms-970402)).

Now in jQuery, you could delegate `focus` event to these elements:

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('focus', '*', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(this);
});
```

[-jsFiddle-](http://jsfiddle.net/rex7dwc2/1/)

As a side note, jQuery UI has a `:focusable` pseudo selector. If you wish to dynamically set `tabindex` attribute to not focusable elements, you could use:

```
$('[contenteditable]').find(':not(:focusable)').attr('tabindex', -1);
```

[-jsFiddle (including jQuery UI)-](http://jsfiddle.net/rex7dwc2/2/)

If you don't want to include jQuery UI just to get `:focusable` pseudo selector, you can create your own custom selector:

```
//include IIFE if not already including jQuery UI
(function () {
    function focusable(element, isTabIndexNotNaN) {
        var map, mapName, img,
        nodeName = element.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        if ("area" === nodeName) {
            map = element.parentNode;
            mapName = map.name;
            if (!element.href || !mapName || map.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== "map") {
                return false;
            }
            img = $("img[usemap='#" + mapName + "']")[0];
            return !!img && $(img).is(':visible');
        }
        return (/^(input|select|textarea|button|object)$/.test(nodeName) ? !element.disabled :
            "a" === nodeName ? element.href || isTabIndexNotNaN : isTabIndexNotNaN) &&
        // the element and all of its ancestors must be visible
        $(element).is(':visible');
    }
    $.extend($.expr[":"], {
        focusable: function (element) {
            return focusable(element, !isNaN($.attr(element, "tabindex")));
        }
    });
})();
```

[-jsFiddle-](http://jsfiddle.net/rex7dwc2/3/)