# replacing focused span by input with focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33897603/841108) gives more details about context and motivation. Notice that I am on Linux and cares *only* about recent Firefox (at least 38) & Chrome.

Basically, I want to edit some AST interactively with a web interface.

In the MELT monitor on [github](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015) commit [7b869102332bd29309](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/commit/7b869102332bd293096f12e1116753363548ed0d) I would like to have a focusable `<span>` (which has `tabindex='0'` so can get focus) which, when I press the spacebar, is replaced by some `<input type='text'/>` which has *already* the focus...

I am not using `contenteditable` anymore, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33540051/841108), because it looks that `contenteditable` is *really* messy (and don't work as well as I want)!

I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bstarynk/16ghx3f6/) containing a simple example with:

```
<div id='mydiv_id'>
   *before* <span id='myspan_id' tabindex='0'>in span</span> !after!
</div>
```

and the JQuery 2 code:

```
var $mydiv = null;
var $myspan = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $myspan = $('#myspan_id');
  $mydiv = $('#mydiv_id');
  console.log (" mydiv=", $mydiv, " myspan=", $myspan);
  $myspan.on("keypress", function (ev) {
     console.log ("myspan keypress ev=", ev);
     if (ev.keyCode === 32 || ev.key === ' ') {
        console.log ("myspan got space ev=", ev);
        var myinput = 
           $("<input type='text' id='myinput_id' width='16' class='myinp_cl'/>");
        $myspan.replaceWith(myinput);
        myinput.focus();
        console.log ("myspan replaced with myinput=", myinput);
      }
   });
  console.log (" mydiv=", $mydiv, " myspan=", $myspan);
});
```

but it does not work as expected.

Or perhaps a focused `<span>` element cannot be replaced (on space keypress) with a focused `<input>` element?

<sup>(in the MELT monitor, I'm using jquery 2.1.4 embedded inside)</sup>

### addenda

the updated jsfiddle works (sorry for my mistake, it needs jquery 2.1.4, with which it is working -and I regret having asked the question here), and since the Javascript of the MELT monitor is AJAX generated, I am not seeing every error in the console (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33582772/841108) question).

NB: In commit [df3bdf3984bc202f](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/commit/df3bdf3984bc202f9aa54c9ac25c9cf344ffceea) I now have a case when, after programmatically moving the focus to a newly created `<input>`,  `$(':focus')` is an empty object, and `document.activeElement` is the `<body>` itself....

<sup>I am now [tempted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311441/841108) to delete this question, it is probably useless...</sup>

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Can't you just set `contenteditable='true'`? https://jsfiddle.net/16ghx3f6/1/

Comment: What's wrong with your code? https://jsfiddle.net/16ghx3f6/2/  (using newer jQuery version supporting `on()` method)

Comment: No, I am understanding that contenteditable is basically unusable for my purpose.

Comment: Still, what is the purpose? And also, what @A.Wolff pointed out, your code seems to work?

Comment: Your code works on jq 2.1.4: https://jsfiddle.net/16ghx3f6/6/   (tested only on chrome but would work on any modern browser supported by jq 2.x)  Even you should replace `if (ev.keyCode === 32 || ev.key === ' ')` by `if(e.which === 32)` [event.which](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) is normalized on jQuery

Comment: Probably, my mistake is elsewhere. Should I delete my question?

Comment: Whatever is your issue(???), it doesn't come from your posted code

Comment: Sorry, my bug is somewhere else. I won't bother you by pasting the 600+ lines of my `webroot/microedit.js` file in github

Comment: `$.fn.jQuery` run this in the console to see what version of jQuery is in the command, i suspect there might be older version of it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Once you have isolated problem, don't hesitate to post new question regarding it. I still don't know what is your issue but keep in mind `keypress` event bubble

Comment: Related [metaquestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311441/841108) about deleting this one!

Answer (score 3):

As i saw your fiddle, what i noticed:

1. You are using `.on()` method.
2. `.on()` is not introduced in jQuery version 1.6.x but 1.7+.

---

So you can change to this:

```
$myspan.keypress(function (ev) {
```

#### [Updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/16ghx3f6/3/)

---

*cares only about recent Firefox (at least 38) & Chrome.*

So, best to upgrade the jQuery version to latest one as possible and take the version `2.x` tree.

Comment: I'd more advice to upgrade jQuery version :)  EDIT: following OP's edit: `(in the MELT monitor, I'm using jquery 2.1.4 embedded inside)` So really not sure what is the issue here

Comment: @A.Wolff agreed and added.

Comment: @A.Wolff i guess there could be another version of jQuery used on the page.

Comment: Ya it would make sense but i guess OP would have seen the error in console. But who knows... :)

Comment: @A.Wolff: I am not seeing every error in the console... Javascript code is ajax generated.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch So is your issue that keypress event not fired? If ya, you should [delegate it](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: @A.Wolff... thanks for your help, I don't understand what is my issue yet.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Firstly try delegating it, e.g: `$(document).on("keypress", "#myspan_id", function (ev) {...});`. If that fixes your issue, you know your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `focus` event on the span like this:

```
var $mydiv = null;
var $myspan = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $myspan = $('#myspan_id');
  $mydiv = $('#mydiv_id');
    $myspan.on('focus', function() { var myinput = 
           $("<input type='text' id='myinput_id' width='16' class='myinp_cl'/>");
        $myspan.replaceWith(myinput);
        myinput.focus();
    });
});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/wLf0e3cs/

Comment: Ok but that's not OP expected behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I want to replace the span when hitting spacebar