# optimizing (nearly minimizing) width of jqueryui menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, firefox

I have a [Jqueryui menu](https://api.jqueryui.com/menu/) which is AJAX generated at runtime. Its *generated* HTML is

```
 <ul id='menu_id'>
   <li>-</li>
   <li>the_system</li>
   <li>the_agenda</li>
 </ul>
```

The first `<li>-</li>` is on purpose a line separator. Ever other list item contains a single word (C-like identifier), such as `<li>this_little_thing</li>`.... The font is not monospaced. The menu should ultimately be used for autocompletion purposes "inside" (actually "over") some `<textarea>`.

Of course, the Javascript is doing something like

```
var mymenu=$("#menu_id");
mymenu.menu({
        select: function(ev,ui) {
           console.log("menu selected ev=", ev, " ui=", ui);
        }
});
```

but I have no idea how to compute the nearly minimal width of that menu. Currently that menu spans the entire width of its container, so is nearly as wide as the web page. I tried several things, such as:

```
    var minwidth = 40;
    /// dont work, the el has same width as body
    mymenu.children("li").each(function(ix,el) {
        console.log("ix=", ix, " el=", el, " .firstChild=", el.firstChild);
        var elw = el.firstChild.clientWidth;
        console.log("ix=", ix, " elw=", elw);
        if (minwidth<elw)
           minwidth=elw;
    });
```

---

#### Gory details

Same context as my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34673243/841108) question: Firefox 38 or 42, Jquery 2.2.0, Jquery-Ui 1.11.4, Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64, for my free software GPL alpha stage [MELT monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015); I'm talking of the commit [e89f3f807ec..](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/commit/e89f3f807ec38a737303b4c39a17b4b90e910326) if that matters. If you are brave enough to build it and test it, run

```
  ./monimelt -Drun,web -W localhost.localdomain:8086/ -J 3
```

then browse http://localhost.localdomain:8086/nanoedit.html and type in the `<textarea>` right to *Command:* the three letters `the`, and then press *simultaneously*  <kbd>Ctrl Space</kbd> ; a completion menu should appear, but it is way too wide!

---

[image: Screenshot of Melt Monitor inside Firefox]

---

<sup>(in the image the menu is in gray, above the `send command`  button near bottom; in my [`webroot/nanoedit.js` file](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/blob/master/webroot/nanoedit.js), it is built in function `mom_cmdkeypress`  after line 215; the `menu_id` HTML5 id is in fact `commandcompletemenu_id` and my Javascript variable is `menuel` not `mymenu`  )</sup>

### Simplified Jsfiddle (MVCE)

This  https://jsfiddle.net/bstarynk/2k464q18/ jsfiddle shows the same issue with HTML

```
 <h2> my menu </h2>
 <div id='mymenudiv_id'>
  <ul id='menu_id'>
    <li>-</li>
    <li>the_system</li>
    <li>the_agenda</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <h2  id='width_id'>-</h2>
```

and javascript:

```
var mymenu;
$(document).ready(function() {
   mymenu = $("#menu_id");
   var mywidth = 40;
   mymenu.children("li").each(function(ix, el) {
     console.log("menu-children ix=", ix, " el=", el);
     var elw = $(el).width();
     console.log("menu-children ix=",ix, " elw=", elw);
     if (mywidth<elw)
        mywidth = elw;
   });
   $("#width_id").html("mywidth="+mywidth.toFixed(0));
   mymenu.menu({
        select: function(ev, ui) {
          console.log("menu-select ev=", ev, " ui=", ui);
   }
 })
})
```

and the standard https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css CSS; on my browser it shows `mywidth=523` which is obviously wrong.
also, replacing `var elw = $(el).width();`  in the JsFiddle with `var elw = el.clientWidth;` don't change anything.

#### simpler question

Perhaps I just want to know what are the CSS3 settings to have an `<ul>` element with vertically aligned small `<li>` elements and *minimal* width to fit the widest `<li>`, but I can't figure that.... so I asked the [CSS3 to make a thin ul fitting its li](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753614/css3-to-make-a-thin-ul-fitting-its-li) question.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are missing the css for menu. An MVCE example that replicates problem would help. There are lots of javascript sandbox sites where this can be set up in minutes

Comment: If using the default one, I still have the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 to make a thin ul fitting its li](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753614/css3-to-make-a-thin-ul-fitting-its-li) -- it looks like the linked question has the answer you were looking for so might as well close this one