# CSS3 to make a thin ul fitting its li

Tags: html, css

Assume the following HTML5 document:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head><title>try</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>testing</h1>
  <ul id='ul_id'>
   <li id='li1_id'>one</li>
   <li id='li2_id'>somelongertwo</li>
  </ul>
</body></html>
```

what would be the CSS3 stylesheet so that the *width* of `<ul id='ul_id'>` element would be the smallest to fit, so would be here the width of `<li id='li2_id'>` plus its bullet, since the second list item is the widest item of the `<ul id='ul_id'>` element?

I don't want the width of my `<ul id='ul_id'>` to be as wide as the containing `<body>`

The context and motivation of this question is my [optimizing (nearly minimizing) width of jqueryui menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751314/optimizing-nearly-minimizing-width-of-jqueryui-menu) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the CSS3 stylesheet so that the width of `<ul id='ul_id'>` element would be the smallest to fit

You could change the `display` of the `ul` element to `inline-block`.

In doing so, it will have a ["shrink-to-fit"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) width based on the size of the children elements.

Based on [section 10.3.9](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inlineblock-width) of the relevant spec for `inline-block` elements in normal flow:

> If `width` is `auto`, the used value is the [shrink-to-fit](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) width as for floating elements.

```css
#ul_id {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul id='ul_id'>
  <li id='li1_id'>one</li>
  <li id='li2_id'>somelongertwo</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, setting the `display` to `table` would result in similar behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ul_id {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
#ul_id {
   float: left;
}
#ul_id:after {
   clear: both;
}
```

One of these two should work as expected.
Width resize to fit container is caused by `display: block` behaviour which is default for `ul` element.